# How to cause css file to work in nav without list

Tags: css, html, nav

I have got a problem with use css file, in tag "nav".
I don't want to have list in nav so I remove that. In the page working on example "line-height", but doesn't work on example "color", "text-decoration".  How can I improve that?

```
nav {
       text-decoration: none;
       width: 7%;
       color:orange;
       overflow: hidden;
       float: left;
       margin-top:20px;
       line-height:55px;
}
```

This is code in html5:

```
<nav >

            <a href="1.html">1 <br />
            <a href="1.html">2 <br />
            <a href="1.html">3 <br />
            <a href="1.html">4 <br />
            <a href="1.html">4 <br />
            <a href="1.html">j4 <br />

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, you are having problem with styling the `a` tag inside the `nav` tag.

Try using the following CSS selector:

```
nav {
   width: 7%;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   margin-top:20px;
   line-height:55px;
}

nav a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color:orange;
}
```